# Replace string in file by specific position

Tags: java

I have a big file (10gb). Each row in the file contains exactly 20 characters.

Is existing way to replace specific whole row to another? (The new row also contains 20 characters)

For example, if i want to replace row number 15,000: I need to replace the characters positions 300,000-300,019 (15,000*20) to another 20 characters.

Comment: have you looked at [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)?

Comment: To find the exact position in the file, you need to know whether it has Unix linebreaks (1 char) or DOS/Windows linebreaks (\r\n, 2 chars), since each 20 char line will take up either 21 or 22 chars in the file. If using a byre oriented means (such as FileChannel, as suggested by @Tibrogargan), you will also need to know how many bytes each char uses. It will be easiest if you can tell from the start that each char is 1 byte (as for US ASCII, for instance).